# simple way to initialize rails application on rake db:create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wrote my rails (3.2.3) application...

config/application.rb:

```
# ...

class MyWebApp
  class Application < Rails::Application

    # ...

    config.before_initialize do
      $my_config = MyConfig.new
    end
  end
end
```

config/database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: true
  database: <%=$my_config.config['db']['basename']%>_development
  pool: 5
  username: <%=$my_config.config['db']['username']%>
  password:
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Then, rake db:create raises:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `config' for nil:NilClass
(erb):15:in `<main>'
/home/sn/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb:838:in `eval'
/home/sn/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb:838:in `result'
/home/sn/dev/mywebapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:115:in `database_configuration'
...
```

After I manually created database, rake db:migrate succeeds. So I read databases.rake and found that db:migrate calls :environment task but db:create does not.

activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:

```
task :create => :load_config do
  configs_for_environment.each { |config| create_database(config) }
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(configs_for_environment.first)
end

task :migrate => [:environment, :load_config] do
  ActiveRecord::Migration.verbose = ENV["VERBOSE"] ? ENV["VERBOSE"] == "true" : true
  ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate(ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrations_paths, ENV["VERSION"] ? ENV["VERSION"].to_i : nil) do |migration|
    ENV["SCOPE"].blank? || (ENV["SCOPE"] == migration.scope)
  end
end
```

Do you know any simple way to initialize $my_config variable correctly on rake db:create?

Answer (score 0):

you can add dependencies to tasks, try to put this line at the end of your Rakefile:

```
namespace :db do 
  task :create => [:environment, :load_config]
end
```